# What is the default timeout of a http GET request using HttpClient in Angular 2

Tags: angular, httpclient

What is the default timeout of a http GET request using HttpClient in Angular 2?
Trying to diagnose if the timeout is from the endpoint (its a big query) or from the request timing out. Can't seem to find any documentation on this anywhere. Angular version 4 if it matters

Comment: Define your own timeout and that will help you to diagnose. Let me know if you need help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure what timesout is the endpoint not angular. Angular can wait forever if the endpoint allows.  - Just my perspective as I do a lot of debugging.. I can hit a break point on a webapi service in the middle of an http request from angular and come into work the next day and resume where I left off perfectly fine with angular having never timed out the request.